# How can I write a fictional college?

Tags: creative-writing

Im having trouble creating a fictional college for my books. I'm trying to make it realistic with a lot of different majors, but I'm only in high school and I don't understand all that much about college.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! A few quick questions to help us come up with a good answer: What role will your college place in your story? What aspects of college life are you hoping to portray? And what research have you done into college life thus far? Could you [edit] the question to clarify those points for us?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer here is, **do your research** - something a writer should do whenever they're inluding a topic they aren't familiar with in their work. If for you that topic is college, research college.

Do you have any older friends studying at a college, or an elder sibling or cousin? Older relatives who are alumni? Acquaintances over a social network? Perhaps even someone who is (or was) a teacher or other employee? Listen when they talk about the daily goings of such a place, and if you can actively *get* them to talk, all the better.

Online resources should be helpful too. Check a few schools' official websites to get an idea of the syllabi and schedules, but what you're likely to find the most useful are blogs or forums where people describe their experience as students, teachers or nonacademic staff. Sites dedicated to advice about navigating the college environment, or even jokes can add some strokes to the picture as well.

If you have a good opportunity to physically visit a college (if you're shy to just go without an excuse, is a lecture for the general public being held there or something?), do that. Don't forget to stroll around the place with eyes open. If you manage to stop to chat with some locals, great.

Even fiction can be your friend - there's a whole genre of campus novel, with names such as Kingsley Amis or David Lodge. It's predominantly British, though, and was most popular deep in the 20th century, so for another country's education system or for today's time the accuracy of its portrayal of things will be limited.

And of course, if everything else fails, if you plan to go to college, you can always just wait a few years and see for yourself what it's like. That will be the best quality source of information you can possibly get.